# How would I delay a power on and power off

Tags: power, capacitor, relay, delay

I need to delay power to the motors for my CNC driver project (using Toshiba TB6560 ICs, which require the motor power to be switched on after logic power and switched off before logic power).

I wanted to use a relay, which would be switched on by a RC delay circuit and enabled the motor power supply, and a big capacitor to supply the logic with power for a while after power off.

This is my current circuit:

[image]

Is this approach a good one? Would the circuit work?

Comment: why do you **want** to use a relay? A P channel MOSFET switch would be more efficient.

Comment: Because I'm switching about 6A of constant current and 12A peak, which seems quite a lot for a transistor and I don't want to add more heat to the controller as well. And I already have some relays which should work.

Comment: Power MOSFETS can switch a lot more than that with very low drain-source resistance - they are not the same as junction transistors.

Comment: I see. And why would you recommend them over relays? And how would I incorporate it into the delay design?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a timer (555) or small microcontroller (Attiny85) for sequencing the power. In fact, I do exactly this for one of my robots.
Tie the source of the MOSFET to the gate of the MOSFET with a pull-up (4.7 kOhm is good) and tie a signal-level N-channel MOSFET like the BS170 to pull that gate down (thus turning on the P-channel) when given signal from the Attiny.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZWdKC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can use the ATtiny to sequence power however you want.

Comment: OK, I thought that avoiding ICs for such a simple circuit will be more elegant, but it turned out not to be as simple as I thought... Only one more question: will the MOSFET require cooling if switching about 8-12A power?

Comment: @MatoušVrba It depends on the FET. You have to look at the datasheet to see what kind of current it can handle and what the junction temperature relationship to the current is. At most, it might need a simple heat sink - there are small ones that bolt directly onto the tab of a TO220 transistor package. Also of note is that to drive the grounding transistor directly from an IC, it must be a "logic level" FET, which the 2n7000 is. This means the gate threshold voltage must be less than the signal voltage coming from the IC.

Comment: I see, but still I don't know what is its advantage over relays...

Comment: And can this switch 24V or will it damage the MOSFET?

Comment: MOSFETs come in all kinds of ratings. A typical rating for power MOSFETs is 30V or 60V. Also, MOSFETs come in all kinds of resistances. A typical Rdson for a high-quality P-channel MOSFET is 10 mOhm, so separate heat sinks is not really needed below 10A.
Main benefit of MOSFETS: They switch on much faster than relays, have no mechanical contacts that wear out, create no EMI, and draw no current to keep the coil energized.
One great part (at $5) is IXTP140P05T rated at 50V DS and 140 Amps DS. (You may need a heat sink above about 10A or so.)